# Is the C++ AMP library useful from F#?

Tags: f#, task-parallel-library, gpgpu, c++-amp

I'm experimenting with the C++ AMP library in F# as a way of using the GPU to do work in parallel. However, the results I'm getting don't seem intuitive.

In C++, I made a library with one function that squares all the numbers in an array, using AMP:

```
extern "C" __declspec ( dllexport ) void _stdcall square_array(double* arr, int n)
{
// Create a view over the data on the CPU
    array_view<double,1> dataView(n, &arr[0]);

// Run code on the GPU
    parallel_for_each(dataView.extent, [=] (index<1> idx) restrict(amp)
    {
        dataView[idx] = dataView[idx] * dataView[idx];
    });

// Copy data from GPU to CPU
    dataView.synchronize();
}
```

(Code adapted from Igor Ostrovsky's [blog](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/09/21/10214538.aspx?Redirected=true) on MSDN.)

I then wrote the following F# to compare the Task Parallel Library (TPL) to AMP:

```
// Print the time needed to run the given function
let time f =
    let s = new Stopwatch()
    s.Start()
    f ()
    s.Stop()
    printfn "elapsed: %d" s.ElapsedTicks

module CInterop =
    [<DllImport("CPlus", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)>]
    extern void square_array(float[] array, int length)

let options = new ParallelOptions()
let size = 1000.0
let arr = [|1.0 .. size|]
// Square the number at the given index of the array
let sq i =
    do arr.[i] <- arr.[i] * arr.[i]
    ()
// Square every number in the array using TPL
time (fun() -> Parallel.For(0, arr.Length - 1, options, new Action<int>(sq)) |> ignore)

let arr2 = [|1.0 .. size|]
// Square every number in the array using AMP
time (fun() -> CInterop.square_array(arr2, arr2.Length))
```

If I set the array size to a trivial number like 10, it takes the TPL ~22K ticks to finish, and AMP ~10K ticks. That's what I expect. As I understand it, a GPU (hence AMP) should be better suited to this situation, where the work is broken into very small pieces, than the TPL.

However, if I increase the array size to 1000, the TPL now takes ~30K ticks and AMP takes ~70K ticks. And it just gets worse from there. For an array of size 1 million, AMP takes nearly 1000x as long as the TPL.

Since I expect the GPU (i.e. AMP) to be better at this kind of task, I'm wondering what I'm missing here.

My graphics card is a GeForce 550 Ti with 1GB, not a slouch as far as I know. I know there's overhead in using PInvoke to call into the AMP code, but I expect that to be a flat cost that is amortized over larger array sizes. I believe the array is passed by reference (though I could be wrong), so I don't expect any cost associated with copying that.

Thank you to everyone for your advice.

Comment: You might also be interested in this, http://registration.gputechconf.com/quicklink/5bCFSh3, S3055 - Dynamic CUDA with F# - New Dimensions for GPU Computing on .NET

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Transferring data back and forth between GPU and CPU takes time. You are most likely measuring your PCI Express bus bandwidth here. Squaring 1M of floats is piece of cake for a GPU.

It's also not a good idea to use the `Stopwach` class to measure performance for AMP because GPU calls can happen asynchronously. In your case it is ok, but if you measure the compute part only (the `parallel_for_each`) this won't work. I think you can use D3D11 performance counters for that.

Comment: Thank you Stringer. I'll add more timers inside the C++ code to see where exactly the time is being spent (and thanks for the tip on the perf counters).

Question to all: if it is a bandwidth issue, is there some way to optimize the transfer of data to/from the GPU? I.e., since games wouldn't bother to use my GPU if they actually took a performance hit from doing so, I'm assuming they're doing something right that I'm not.

Comment: @FSharpN00b That's a rather large question.  One way to do that would be to incrementally move data to the gpu so the gpu and do some work while its waiting for the rest of the data

Comment: @mydogisbox Yes, this is a valid strategy for hiding data transfer by overlapping it with compute.

Comment: Thank you mydogisbox and Ade. It sounds as though I should stick to the TPL and only worry about asynchronously moving data to the GPU after I've maxed out the CPU (which isn't likely), rather than trying to go to the GPU first. Thank you to all for your replies.